# SQL Server: date conversion problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT     'Last 7 Days' AS Date_Range, CONVERT(smalldatetime, GETDATE()) - 6 AS Begin_Date, CONVERT(smalldatetime, GETDATE()) 
                      AS End_Date
FROM         sys.columns
```

produces output

```
Last 7 Days 2011-03-20 07:35:00 2011-03-26 07:35:00
Last 7 Days 2011-03-20 07:35:00 2011-03-26 07:35:00
```

How to get this?

```
Last 7 Days 2011-03-20 00:00:00 2011-03-26 00:00:00
Last 7 Days 2011-03-20 00:00:00 2011-03-26 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a DateAdd operation on the DT value you're getting back. This essentially removes the time component:

```
DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use date in the convert function instead of smalldatetime and then append "00:00:00" as string to the result.